# Mapping and update data in database

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, sql-server, add-in

We have two feature layers:

- layer A - drainage segment layer (along road outline)
- layer B - road centre line layer.

In my SQL Server database I have a table storing the mapping information of segment ID (from layer A) and Road name (from layer B).

[image]

The problem is that when I create a new polyline feature (a segment) in layer A, I need to update the database table also. I am stuck here.

I do not know how to update the database table at the same time as when a user creates a new feature in layer A.

Should I create a new geoprocess (using python script) to do so?

Is there any other solution for it?

I am using vb.net arcmap addin (vs 2012), arcmap 10.2 and sql server 2008 r2.